# Replace HW interrupt in flat memory mode with DOS32/A

Tags: dos, interrupt, isr, watcom

I have a question about how to replace HW interrupt in flat memory mode...

1. about my application...

   - created by combining **Watcom C** and **DOS32/A**.
   - written for running on DOS mode( not on OS mode )
   - with DOS32/A now I can access >1M memory and allocate large memory to use...(running in **flat memory mode** !!!)
2. current issue...

   - I want to write an ISR(interrupt service routine) for one PCI card. Thus I need to "replace" the HW interrupt.
   - Ex. the PCI card's interrupt line = 0xE in DOS. That means this device will issue interrupt via 8259's IRQ 14.

*But I did not how to achieve my goal to **replace** this interrupt in flat mode ?*

@ resource I found...
- in watcom C's library, there is one sample using _dos_getvect, _dos_setvect, and _chain_intr to hook INT 0x1C...
I tested this code and found OK. But when I apply it to my case: INT76 ( where IRQ 14 is "INT 0x76" <- (14-8) + 0x70 ) then nothing happened...

- I checked HW interrupt is generated but my own ISR did not invoked...

Do I lose something ? or are there any functions I can use to achieve my goal ?

===============================================================

*[20120809]*
I tried to use **DPMI** calls **0x204 and 0x205** and found **MyISR()** is still not invoked. I described what I did as below and maybe you all can give me some suggestions !

**1)** Use inline assembly to implement DPMI calls 0x204 and 0x205 and test OK...

Ex. Use DPMI **0x204** to show the interrupt vectors of 16 IRQs and I get(*selector:offset*) following results: **8:1540**(INT8),**8:1544**(INT9),.....,**8:1560**(INT70),**8:1564**(INT71),...,**8:157C**(INT77)

Ex. Use DPMI **0x205** to set the interrupt vector for **IRQ14**(INT76) and returned CF=0, indicating successful

**2)** Create my own ISR MyISR() as follows:

```
volatile int tick=0;  // global and volatile...
void MyISR(void)
{
  tick = 5;  // simple code to change the value of tick...
}
```

**3)** Set **new** interrupt vector by DPMI call 0x205:

```
selector = FP_SEG(MyISR);  // selector = 0x838 here
offset = FP_OFF(MyISR);    // offset   = 0x30100963 here
sts = DPMI_SetIntVector(0x76, selector, offset, &out_ax);
```

Then sts = 0(CF=0) indicating successful !

- One strange thing here is:my app runs in **flat memory model** and I think the selector should be 0 for MyISR()... But if selector = 0 for DPMI call 0x205 then I got CF=1 and AX = 0x8022, indicating "invalid selector" !

**4)** Let HW interrupt be generated and the evidences are:

- PCI device config register 0x5 bit2(Interrupt Disabled) = 0
- PCI device config register 0x6 bit3(Interrupt status) = 1
- PCI device config register 0x3C/0x3D (Interrupt line) = 0xE/0x2
- In DOS the interrupt mode is PIC mode(8259 mode) and Pin-based(MSIE=0)

**5)** Display the value of tick and found it is still **"0"**...

Thus I think MyISR() is not invoked correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [DPMI Function 0204h](http://dos32a.narechk.net/manual/html/prog/int31h/0204.htm) and [0205h](http://dos32a.narechk.net/manual/html/prog/int31h/0205.htm) instead of '_dos_getvect' and '_dos_setvect', respectively.

The runtime environment of your program is DOS32A or a DPMI Server/host. So use the api they provided instead of using DOS int21h facilities. But DOS32A does intercepts int21h interrupts, so your code should work fine, as far as real mode is concerned.

Actually what you did is you install only *real mode* interrupt handler for IRQ14 by using '_dos_getvect' and '_dos_setvect' functions.

By using the DPMI functions instead, you install *protected mode* interrupt handler for IRQ14, and DOS32a will autopassup IRQ14 interrupt to this protected mode handler.

Recall: A dos extender/DPMI server can be in protected mode or real mode while an IRQ is asserted.

This is becoz your application uses some DOS or BIOS API, so extender needs to switch to real mode to execute them and the return back to protected mode to transfer control to you protected mode application.

DOS32a does this by allocating a real-mode callback (at least for hardware interrupts) which calls your protected mode handler if IRQ14 is asserted while the Extender is in real-mode.

If the extender is in protected mode, while IRQ14 is asserted, it will automatically transfer control to your IRQ14 handler.

But if you didn't install protected mode handler for your IRQ, then DOS32a, will not allocate any real-mode callback, and your real-mode irq handler may not get control.
But it should recieve control AFAIK.

Anyway give the above two functions a try. And do *chain* to the previous int76h interrupt handler as Sean said.

In short:

In case of DOS32a, you need not use '_dos_getvect' and '_dos_setvect' functions. Instead use the DPMI functions 0204h and 0205h for installing your protected mode IRQ handler.

An advise : In your interrupt handler the first step should be to check *whether your device actually generated interrupt* or it is some other device sharing this irq(IRQ14 in your case). You can do this by checking a *'interrupt pending bit' in your device*, if it is set, service your device and chain to next handler. If it is not set to 1, simply chain to next handler.

**EDITED:**
Use the [latest](http://dos32a.narechk.net/content/download.html) version of DOS32a, instead of one that comes with OW.

**Update on 2012-08-14:**

Yes, you can use FP_SEG and FP_OFF macros for obtaining selector and offset respectively, just like you would use these macros in real modes to get segment and offset.

You can also use MK_FP macro to create far pointers from selector and offset. eg. 
MK_FP(selector, offset).

You should declare your interrupt handler with ' __interrupt ', keyword when writing handlers in C.

Here is a snippet:

```
             #include <i86.h>  /* for FP_OFF, FP_SEG, and MK_FP in OW */

             /* C  Prototype for your IRQ handler */
             void   __interrupt    __far irqHandler(void);
                        .
                        . 
                        .
          irq_selector = (unsigned short)FP_SEG( &irqHandler );
          irq_offset = (unsigned long)FP_OFF( &irqHandler );

          __dpmi_SetVect( intNum, irq_selector, irq_offset );
                        .
                        . 
                        .
```

or, try this:

```
          extern void sendEOItoMaster(void);  
          # pragma aux sendEOItoMaster = \                         
                "mov  al,    0x20"  \       
                "out  0x20,  al"    \       
                modify [eax] ;



          extern void sendEOItoSlave(void);  
          # pragma aux sendEOItoSlave = \                           
              "mov  al,    0x20"  \       
              "out  0xA0,  al"    \       
              modify [eax] ;


      unsigned int   old76_selector, new76_selector;
      unsigned long  old76_offset, new76_offset;


      volatile int chain = 1; /* Chain to the old handler */
      volatile int tick=0;  // global and volatile...


     void (__interrupt __far *old76Handler)(void) = NULL;      // function pointer declaration

     void __interrupt __far new76Handler(void) {


            tick = 5;  // simple code to change the value of tick...

               .
               .
               .

           if( chain ){

                 // disable irqs if enabled above.

                 _chain_intr( old76Handler );  // 'jumping' to the old handler

                //  ( *old76Handler )();          // 'calling' the old handler 

           }else{

               sendEOItoMaster();
               sendEOItoSlave();
           }

      }


      __dpmi_GetVect( 0x76, &old76_selector, &old76_offset );

      old76Handler = ( void (__interrupt __far *)(void) ) MK_FP (old76_selector, old76_offset)

      new76_selector = (unsigned int)FP_SEG( &new76Handler );
      new76_offset = (unsigned long)FP_OFF( &new76Handler );

      __dpmi_SetVect( 0x76, new76_selector, new76_offset );

                    .
                    .
```

NOTE:

You should first double check that the IRQ# you are hooking is *really* assigned/mapped  to the interrupt pin of your concerned PCI device. IOWs, first read *'Interrupt Line register'* (NOT Interrupt Pin register) from PCI configuration space, and hook only that irq#. The valid values for this register, in your case are: 0x00 through 0x0F inclusive, with 0x00 means IRQ0 and 0x01 means IRQ1 and so on.

POST/BIOS code writes a value in 'Interrupt Line register', while booting, and you MUST NOT modify this register at any cost.(of course, unless you are dealing with interrupt routing issues which an OS writer will deal with)

You should also get and save the selector and offset of the old handler by using DPMI call 0204h, in case you are chaining to old handler. If not, don't forget to send EOI(End-of-interrupt) to BOTH master and slave PICs  in case you hooked an IRQ belonging to slave PIC(ie INT 70h through 77h, including INT 0Ah), and ONLY to master PIC in case you hooked an IRQ belonging to master PIC.

In flat model, the BASE address is 0 and Limit is 0xFFFFF, with G bit(ie Granularity bit) = 1.

The base and limit(along with attribute bits(e.g G bit) of a segment) reside in the descriptor corresponding to a particular segment. The descriptor itself, sits in the descriptor table.

Descriptor tables are an array with each entry being 8bytes.

The selector is merely a pointer(or an index) to the 8-byte descriptor entry, in the Descriptor table(either GDT or LDT). So a selector CAN'T be 0.

Note that lowest 3 bits of 16-bit selector have special meaning, and only the upper 13-bits are used to index a descriptor entry from a descriptor table.

GDT = Global Descriptor Table

LDT = Local Descriptor Table

A system can have only one GDT, but many LDTs.

As entry number 0 in GDT, is reserved and can't be used. AFAIK, DOS32A, does not create any LDT for its applications, instead it simply allocate and initalize descriptor entries corresponding to the application, in GDT itself.

Selector MUST not be 0, as x86 architecture regards 0 selector as invalid, when you try to access memory with that selector; though you can successfully place 0 in any segment register, it is only when you try to access(read/write/execute) that segment, the cpu generates an exception.

In case of interrupt handlers, the base address need not be 0, even in case of flat mode.
The DPMI environment must have valid reasons for doing this so.
After all, you still need to tackle segmentation at some level in x86 architecture.

```
                  PCI device config register 0x5 bit2(Interrupt Disabled) = 0

                  PCI device config register 0x6 bit3(Interrupt status) = 1
```

I think, you mean Bus master command  and status registers respectively. They actually reside in either I/O space or memory space, but NOT in PCI configuration space.
So you can read/write them directly via IN/OUT or MOV, instructions.

For reading/writing, PCI configuration registers you must use configuration red/write methods or PCI BIOS routines.

NOTE:

Many PCI disk controllers, have a bit called 'Interrupt enable/disable' bit. The register
that contains this bit is usually in the PCI configuration space, and can be found from the datasheet.

Actually, this setting is for "forwarding" the interrupt generated by the device attached to the PCI controller, to the PCI bus.

If, interrupts are disabled via this bit, then even if your device(attached to PCI controller) is generating the interrupt, the interrupt will NOT be forwarded to the PCI bus(and hence cpu will never know if interrupt occurred), but the interrupt bit(This bit is different from 'Interrupt enable/disable' bit) in PCI controller is still set to notify that the device(attached to PCI controller, eg a hard disk) generated an interrupt, so that the program can read this bit and take appropriate actions. It is similar to polling, from programming perspective.

This usually apply only for non-bus master transfers.

But, it seems that you are using bus master transfers(ie DMA), so it should not apply in your case.

But anyway, I would suggest you do read the datasheet of the PCI controller carefully, especially looking for bits/registers related to interrupt handling

**EDITED:**

Well, as far as application level programming is concerned, you need not encounter/use _far pointers, as your program will not access anything outside to your code.

But this is not completely true, when you go to system-level  programming, you need to access memory mapped device registers, external ROM, or implementing interrupt handlers, etc.

The story changes here. The creation of  a segment ie allocating descriptor and getting its associated selector, ensures that even if there is a bug in code, it will not annoyingly change anything external to that particular segment from which current code is executing. If it tries to do so, cpu will generate a fault. So when accessing external devices(especially memory mapped device's registers), or accessing some rom data, eg BIOS etc., it is a good idea to have allocate a descriptor and set the base and segment limits according to the area you need to execute/read/write  and proceed. But you are not bound to do so.

Some external code residing for eg in rom, assume that they will be invoked with a far call.

As I said earlier, in x86 architecture, at some level(the farther below you go) you need to deal with segmentation as there is no way to disable it completely.
But in flat model, segmentation is present as an aid to programmer, as I said above, when accessing external(wrt to your program) things. But you need not use if you don't desire to do so.

When an interrupt handler is invoked, it doesn't know the base and limits of program that was interrupted. It doesn't know the segment attributes, limits etc. of the interrupted program, we say except CS and EIP all registers are in undefined state wrt interrupt handler. So it is needed to be declared as far function to indicate that it resides somewhere external to currently executing program.

Comment: I have completed the DPMI calls 0x204 and 0x205 for getting and setting the interrupt vector using inline assembly. But now I have 2 questions: (1) How to decide the "selector" and "offset" address when using DPMI 0x205(Set Vector) ? (Is there any API for this purpose, like FP_SEG() and FP_OFF() ? ) (2) Do I need to use keyword "_interrupt" when declaring my own service routine ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @liaoo- see the *Update on 2012-08-14* section of my answer.

Comment: Dear jacks, thanks for your valuable & practical information and I will try it ASAP. But I still have 2 questions about your information: **(1)** You said **MK_FP()**, **FP_SEG()**, and **FP_OFF()** are still OK to use in flat mode, right ? But I found below words in [here](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/watfaq.shtml) _...you never need to deal with 64K segment limits, or strange keywords like FAR, NEAR or MK_FP..._ what does it mean ? **(2)** I can use **DPMI 204** to get the selector and offset of OldISR, but how to **invoke** it if I need to "chain" it within NewISR ?

Comment: @liaoo- See the code section in answer. I modified it accordingly. Also have a look at *edited* section.

Comment: Dear jacks, my own service routine is successfully invoked based on your information/code... Much thanks for your help !

Comment: Dear jacks, I have 2 more questions about interrupt service routine...maybe you can help me to clarify them ! **(1)** should I use _iret_ or _iretd_ at the **"end"** of **MyISR()** ? (that is, EOI master and slave then iret...) **(2)** Can I always _chain_ **oldISR()** ? (assume oldISR works and it will distinguish then do correct things)

Comment: @liaoo- glad to know that things worked! :)  Well, if you are writing interrupt handler in assembly, then you MUST use *iretd*. But in your case, since you are writing in C and using the *' __interrupt '*, keyword, you DON'T need to put separate ired via inline assembly. The compiler will take care of that(ONLY if you write ISR with '_interrupt' keyword, otherwise there is no way for the compiler to distinguish between an function and ISR). The C compiler will put appropriate instructions when it encounter '}' ie enclosing curly bracket of your ISR, while compiling.  If you ...

Comment: ... are NOT sending EOIs in your ISR code then you MUST chain to old ISR, otherwise you don't need to chain, if you are handling EOIs yourself. But note that if you ARE handling EOIs in your code, then you MUST not chain to old ISR, otherwise it might get confused.  Also, the default ISRs are installed by POST code during booting, so you are ensured that they will be last in the chain, and will send EOIs, themselves. Also note that the pci device that genrated the interrupt will 'clear the interrupt occured bit' as soon as your ISR reads that to confirm that your device actually asserted...

Comment: ...  irq, so in such case you should send EOIs your self and do not chain to the old handler. Becoz if now(interrupt bit cleared) you chain to the old handler, the handler will think that device didn't generated interrupt. In short, if you are sure that your device assreted the irq, then completely handle it and send EOI in last, and do not chain. But if you are sure that some other device has asserted this irq(recall: pci interrupts are shared.), then you must simply chain to old handler, without doing any further processing.

Comment: jacks, what does _"...pci device that genrated the interrupt will 'clear the interrupt occured bit' as soon as your ISR reads that to confirm that your device actually asserted irq..."_ mean ? ( I guess: if PCI device generates interrupt then its IS(Interrupt Status) bit = 1; then in our ISR we should check if IS bit = 1 by reading it...Then **pci device itself** will clear IS bit ? ) am I right ? (here IS bit = PCI config space offset 0x6 bit3...)

Comment: jacks, I think I can **always chain** the old isr _no matter this interrupt is shared or not_ becoz: **(1)** if interrupt is not shared then the old isr will be the dummy one(in which EOI is sent), or **(2)** if interrupt shared the interrupt chain will be like: myISR->oldISR->Dummy. In this case after my handler is executed and control transfer to oldISR, but no device generates interrupt, then control pass to dummy ISR and EOI is sent... _In both cases myISR is executed and EOI is sent correctly_ thus everything is fine... Am I right ?

Comment: @liaoo- I think this is a terminology issue. Ok, first thing, PCI device config register 0x6 bit3(Interrupt status) and PCI device config register 0x5 bit2(Interrupt Disabled) , bits are NOT standard bis in every PCI device(even if the device generates interrupt via INT#x pin). For, eg, you can refer any Intel I/O hub data sheet and look out for IDE controller PCI config. space registers. In such pci devices, theses bits(IS and IE) reside somewhere else in configuration space. What type of AHCI controller you are using - expansion card or integrated on motherboard?

Comment: .. . In case of AHCI controllers it might be possible that these two reserved bits are used for the purposes you mentioned, BUT it is NOT standard for other devices. So, you MUST check the datasheet for the actual meaning of these 2 bits, and whether the  pci device itself will clear IS bit. The bits I talked about ie ID(interrupt disabled) and IS serve the following purposes:  ID in AHCI controller, if reset will  "forward" the interrupt generated by the SATA device in your case, to the PCI bus and thus assert an IRQ whenever SATA device generates an interrupt. The IS  will be set ...

Comment: ...  whenever SATA device generates an interrupt. no matter whether ID is set or reset. The interrupt will NOT be forwarded to PCI bus(ie IRQ will not be asserted), if ID is set. And whenever, you read the IS bit when it is set, the PCI device usually clears it *automatically*. It's just that. So, as I said earlier, you need to revisit datasheet.for the exact meaning and action of the bits you are talking about ie ID and IS.  The second thing, is as far as chaining to old ISR is concerned, yes you can *always* chain to the old ISR, BUT you must NOT send EOI in your ISR, if you are chaining.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since I fiddled with interrupts, but the table is a pointer to set where the processor should go to to process an interrupt. I can give you the process, but not code, as I only ever used 8086 code.

Pseudo code:

```
Initialize:
    Get current vector - store value
    Set vector to point to the entry point of your routine
```

next:

```
Process Interrupt:
    Your code decides what to do with data
    If it's your data:
        process it, and return
    If not:
        jump to the stored vector that we got during initialize, 
        and let the chain of interrupts continue as they normally would
```

finally:

```
Program End:
    check to see if interrupt still points to your code
        if yes, set vector back to the saved value
        if no, set beginning of your code to long jump to vector address you saved, 
            or set a flag that lets your program not process anything
```

Comment: Although that is not what I want now,but still thanks for your detailed "process information" because what you said is the second step for me. Now my routine can NOT be invoked thus I can not continue ^_^   And I did not know exactly about the part of "Program End", could you explain in more detailed ? Ex. why need to see if interrupt still points to my code ?

Comment: when your program no longer needs to process interrupts, it needs to unload itself. If something else has hooked into the interrupts, then you cannot unload by resetting the vector (as you break the new program), and have to give a message about *unload programs in the reverse order you loaded them*